# get class element when using click function

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.paper_img').click(function(){

            console.log("hello")

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

how can I access the element which triggered this function?
thanks
carl

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword will give you access to the invoker.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.paper_img').click(function() {
    $('div').html($(this).attr('id') + ' was clicked!');    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button_1" class="paper_img">Click me!</button>
<button id="button_2" class="paper_img">Click me!</button>
<button id="button_3" class="paper_img">Click me!</button>
<button id="button_4" class="paper_img">Click me!</button>
<div></div>
```